# Are the following two subspaces equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the subspace $V$ generated from the vectors $v_1=(1,1,1)$ and $v_2=(0,1,1)$  equal to the subspace $W$ generated by $v_3=(1,0,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1,1)$?

Comment: No, $V$ is $2$-dimensional and $W$ is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Can you use linear combinations of $v_3,v_2$ to write $v_1$?

Comment: Isn't there a typo? $v_3=v_2$.

Comment: Sorry!!! I was wrong in writing $v_3$

Comment: I edited it....

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious, since $v_3=v_1-v_2$, hence $\operatorname{span}(v_2,v_3)\subset\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$ The reverse inclusion results from $v_1=v_2+v_3$.